# stackoverflowException

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

I have written code below.but it will print this exception and i really don't know what is its problem,please help me thanks

CODE:

```
    private void fillMinAverageTime() {   //T(n) = O(n^3)
    for (int i = list.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            for (k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                minOne = fillMinAverageTimeArray(i, j);
                if (min == 0.0) {
                    min = minOne;
                } else if (minOne < min) {
                    min = minOne;
                }
            }
            min = 0.0;
            minOne = 0.0;
            minAverageTimeArray[i][j] = min + probability[i][j];


        }

    }
}

private double fillMinAverageTimeArray(int i, int j) {
    if (i > j) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    if (i == j) {
        return minAverageTimeArray[i][i];
    }
   System.out.println(k+","+j+","+i);//EDITED

 **return (fillMinAverageTimeArray(i, k - 1) + fillMinAverageTimeArray(k + 1, j));**//the line tat throws this exception
}
```

Exception:

```
at OBST.MemoizedVersion.fillMinAverageTimeArray(MemoizedVersion.java:118)
at OBST.MemoizedVersion.fillMinAverageTimeArray(MemoizedVersion.java:118)
at OBST.MemoizedVersion.fillMinAverageTimeArray(MemoizedVersion.java:118)
```

EDITED: it will print:

```
2,3,2
3,3,2
1,2,1
2,2,1
1,3,1
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
```

Comment: Where is the `k` in that method coming from?

Comment: k is a global variable !

Comment: Please add a log message printing out i, k, j above the line which causes the StackOverflowException.

Comment: @user472221 - there aren't any global variables in Java, you probably meant a field. Anyway, you shouldn't use fields for passing values from one method to another. That's what method parameters are for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have written a [recursive method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function). You have to be sure that it will terminate by reaching the base case, otherwise it could go into a loop until a stack overflow exception occurs - which is what is happening here. The easiest way to guarantee termination is to always ensure that you get closer to your base case on every call. Your base case here is that the arguments `i` and `j` at some point must become equal, so you should try to bring them at least one closer to each other at every step.

Here's the line that gives the problem:

```
return (fillMinAverageTimeArray(i, k - 1) + fillMinAverageTimeArray(k + 1, j));
```

This is just going to call your method with the same values repeatedly. Are you sure you didn't mean `i + 1` and `j - 1` instead of `k + 1` and `k - 1`?

Comment: @user472221: You aren't changing the value of `k` - you are just calling the function `fillMinAverageTimeArray` over and over and over with the same values `i`,  and `k - 1`. You never make any progress. Try adding some debug lines that print out the values of `i` and `j` inside the recursive function, and you should see the problem - they never change.

Comment: @user472221: It's not clear to me what your method should return. You could making `k` to a local variable instead of a global and passing it in as a parameter to your function. But how exactly it should be used is not totally clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark already said make sure that your recursive call terminates correctly.

If it still overflows then your recursion simply is to deep.

Hacky solution, use the JVM's `-Xss` flag to [change the stack size](http://www.dgtech.co.kr/resin-doc/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp#stack-size).

Correct solution, use an iterative approach and roll your own stack.